# ID Story where a medical doctor is sent back in time to improve health

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I recall reading a short story where a doctor (not *the* doctor) time travels and brings modern medicine to ancient rome (I think).

The improved health leads to massive overpopulation in the present, despite technological advances that remove the oceans to make more surface area, and cities that build far underground and tall skyscrapers, etc.

Then, another time traveler is sent back in time to murder the first.

I probably read this sometime in the early 2000's or late 1990's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is ["The Deadly Mission of Phineas Snodgrass"](http://www.uchronia.net/bib.cgi/label.html?id=pohldeadly) by Frederik Pohl, first published in *Galaxy* in June 1962.

It is apparently a satire of L. Sprague de Camp's 1939 novel *Lest Darkness Fall*, which has a similar premise, except that everything goes fine and the Dark Ages are averted.  The [Wikipedia page for *Lest Darkness Fall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lest_Darkness_Fall) has a mention of "Snodgrass", which is how I found out about the latter, and gives the following plot summary:

> A response to this story is "The Deadly Mission of Phineas Snodgrass" by Frederik Pohl, in which a man travels back to 1 BC and teaches modern medicine, causing a population explosion. It ends with the fantastically overpopulated alternate timeline sending someone back to assassinate the title character, allowing darkness to fall for thankful billions.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!